# SASS or LESS Keyframes percentage loop

Tags: loops, sass, less, css-animations

I'm testing something special and I'm trying to loop inside keyframes to dynamically write percentages into it.

I've tested something like that with SASS but it doesn't work.

```
@keyframes test{

    @for $i from 0 through 100 {
        #{$i}% {
            //do special stuff
        } 
        $i: $i + 1;
    }
```

I want it to output :

```
@keyframes test{
    0%{
          ...
    }
    1%{
          ...
    }
    2%{
          ...
    }
    3%{
          ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But I got

```
Error on line number: 23. Invalid CSS after "    #{$i}%": expected placeholder name, was " {"
```

I've tested this in LESS and it doesn't work either.

```
    @a: 0%;

    @keyframes test{

       .func (@a, @b, @c);

    }

    .func (@a, @b, @c) when (@a < 100%){  
        (@a){
            //do special stuff
        }

        .func (@a+1, @b, @c);
    }
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: For `@for` loops in Sass, you don't need to manually add to `$i` in the loop. Remove `$i: $i + 1;` and it will still work.

Answer (score 23):

It will work if you finagle it like this:

```
@keyframes test {
  @for $i from 0 through 100 {
    #{$i * 1%} {
      // do special stuff
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## LESS version

requires the `.for` mixin

- https://github.com/pixelass/more-or-less/blob/master/less/fn/_for.less

### NOTICE

This is a NON inline-js version for maximum compatibility

### INPUT

```
@keyframes crazy {
    .for(0,100);.-each(@i){
        @selector: e('@{i}%');

        @{selector} {
            /* do crazy stuff */
        }
    }
}
```

### OUTPUT

```
@keyframes crazy {
  0% {
    /* do crazy stuff */
  }
  1% {
    /* do crazy stuff */
  }
  2% {
    /* do crazy stuff */
  }
  3% {
    /* do crazy stuff */
  }
  4% {
    /* do crazy stuff */
  }
    ...etc
}
```

Comment: Is still required this *.for* mixin on LESS 2.7.1?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Less does not support loops: http://lesscss.org/functions/#functions-overview : I case you're interested take a look at this https://github.com/pixelass/homeless  it is better and faster than "more-or-less"

Comment: I will close soon my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404204/how-to-iterate-keyframe-percentages-less-css) then. But I have seen people [looping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ex0ndyb_E5w") with native LESS.

Comment: Eventually I got a working answer for this (by @Harry) without the need of install an external Less library. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404204/how-to-iterate-keyframe-percentages-less-css)

Answer (score 1):

Sass apparently needs a value defined as percentage for it to render correctly.
This example generates keyframes to animate a background, but you can change both the list of values and the property to animate.

## SASS

```
//Given a list of colors
$COLORS: $COLOR-MAIN #f39d75 #c1cecd #f3f57e

// Define a mixin
=animate-color-keyframes($list: $COLORS, $property: background)
    //declare the first keyframe statically
    0%
        #{$property}: nth($list, -1)
    @for $i from 1 through length($list)
        // calculate the keyframe percentage
        $percentage: $i / length($list)
        $keyframe: percentage($percentage)
        // render keyframes
        #{$keyframe}
            #{$property}: nth($list, $i)

// .....
@keyframes change-bg-color
    +animate-color-keyframes
```

## CSS OUTPUT

```css
@keyframes change-bg-color {
  0% {
    background: #f3f57e; }
  25% {
    background: #abf0b3; }
  50% {
    background: #f39d75; }
  75% {
    background: #c1cecd; }
  100% {
    background: #f3f57e; } 
}
```